# indices of the max values of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to return the indices of the max values of an array of integers by passing variable length array into a method.  How do loop through an array then return one or multiple values

This what I have so far:

```
public static int methodname3(int d[]) { //separate method with array

    int largest = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if ( d[i] > largest ) 
        {
           largest = d[i];
           index = i;
        }

    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: What about if the numbers are all negative... maybe starting largest at Integer.MIN_VALUE would be a good idea...

Comment: `indices of the max values` How many max values can be there unless they all are same?

Comment: yep - the same max values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return multiple indices you'll need something more than an **int**. Depending on how you plan on handling the data afterwards, I would suggest either returning an **array** or a **String** and then passing that value to another method for processing.

I would suggest breaking the problem down into 2 parts, first finding and counting the number of instances of the max value, then grabbing the indices of the max values. If you want to return the indices in an array you'll need to step through it twice (this is using standard arrays, not ArrayLists, which are extensible). If you want to return the indices as a String you'll only need to do a single pass.

```
public static int[] methodname3(int d[]) {
    int largest = d[0] - 1; // this makes sure that negative values are checked
    int instances = 0;
    int[] indices = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if (d[i] > largest){
            largest = d[i];
            instances = 1;
        }
        else if(d[i] == largest){
            instances++;
        }
    }

    indices = new int[instances];

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if(d[i] == largest){
            indices[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```

If you want to return the indices as a String you could do the entire thing in one pass like this:

```
public static String methodname3(int d[]){
    int largest = d[0] - 1;
    String indices = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if (d[i] > largest){
            largest = d[i];
            indices = i; // This resets the String each time a larger value is found
        }
        else if(d[i] == largest){
            indices = indices + " " + i; 
            // This results in a space delimited String of indices
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I get a variable might not have been initialized issue on the first solution - in this area     for(int i, j = 0; i < d.length; i++){
        if(d[i] == largest){
            indices[j] = i;
            j++;
        }

Comment: Oh, I forgot to initialize 'i' again. I'll edit the post to fix this. (It should be initiated the way 'j' is initialized).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be rather than using int index, use an array of integers, add the index to the array as you loop through and then return the array.

Something like this:

```
        public static int methodname3(int d[])  //separate method with array
    {     
        int largest = 0;
        int index[];
        int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if ( d[i] > largest ) 
        {
            largest = d[i];
            index[c] = i;
            c++;
        }

    }
    return index[];
}
```

Comment: A list could be used instead...
    List<Integer> maxIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    maxIndices.add(i);

Comment: The return type is also incorrect should be 
public static List<Integer> methodname3(int d[])

Answer (score 0):

As following the above method, there it is: return a list containing the indexes

```
public List<Integer> methodname3(int d[])  //separate method with array
    {     
        int largest = 0;
        List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if ( d[i] > largest ) 
        {
            largest = d[i];
            index.add(i);
        }

    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work. As you stated your input can have multiple `max` values and you want to `return` something from your method you should consider some form of list(I used `ArrayList`). In the `main` just `iterate` over the list and print the values.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getIndices(int[] arr) {
        ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == max) {
                output.add(j);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```